# Form validation in React Bootstrap with different validation conditions for each field

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-bootstrap

I'm new to react-bootstrap and js and am trying to create a simple form validation with 2 just fields - name and email but I want them to have different validation logic (i.e. the email should check whether it's a valid email whereas the name should check whether it's empty).

Looking at the [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#forms-validation-native), it is mostly what I want, except the part where the fields are considered valid as long as they are not empty and I can't figure out how to change the validation logic only for a specific field. Is there a way to do so?

In case it's unclear, I want the same text box behaviour as the one in the documentation where after clicking the submit button, the text box will be updated with green or red borders as the user types valid or invalid input respectively without clicking the submit button again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out after looking through the HTML input attributes. I have to add `pattern` and change `type` to `email`.

From [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email#validation), the `required` attribute will check if it's empty and the `type="email"` will have basic email validation with an equivalent regex to

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}
[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/
```

and if more advanced validation is needed, then add `pattern` attribute to specify a custom regex.

Editing the code slightly from the documentation in my post.

```
function FormExample() {
  const [validated, setValidated] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    const form = event.currentTarget;
    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }

    setValidated(true);
  };

  return (
    <Form noValidate validated={validated} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Form.Row>
        <Form.Group as={Col} md="6" controlId="validationCustom03">
          <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Name" required/>
          <Form.Control.Feedback>Looks good!</Form.Control.Feedback>
          <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">Please provide a valid name.</Form.Control.Feedback>
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group as={Col} md="3" controlId="validationCustom04">
          <Form.Label>Gmail</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Gmail" required pattern=".+@gmail\.com"/>
          <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">Please provide a valid gmail.</Form.Control.Feedback>
          <Form.Control.Feedback type="valid">Looks good!</Form.Control.Feedback>
        </Form.Group>
      </Form.Row>
      <Button type="submit">Submit form</Button>
    </Form>
  );
}
```